# Modern SharePoint Translate Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-onlineapp

is there a solution to translate a text from a newspost in lifetime?
For example: I´ve create a new newspost in english. My collegue from mexico wants also read this newspost in spanish. Can i solve this with a button "translate" like social media (instagram ...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, [Machine Translation Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint) are now unavailable and unsupported in SharePoint Online.

You can however create your [page translations](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-multilingual-sharepoint-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c) in modern Communication sites (and soon modern Team sites). This would mean manually translating your page content. Alternatively, you could create your own custom functionality to [create page translations programmatically](https://www.eliostruyf.com/multilingual-apis-modern-sharepoint) and then translate the page content using a third party API.